# Sending a JSON with request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using request module to send data to a server.

I wrote this:

```
... 
      var httpOptions = {
        host: localStorage.host,
        path: localStorage.path,
        port: localStorage.port,
        method: 'POST',
        body: $scope.jsonToSend,
        json: true,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      };
 ...

try {
        var request = http.request(httpOptions, httpCallback);
        request.on('error', function(err) {
          $scope.hasHttpError = true;
          $scope.httpErrorMessage = 'NETWORK error '+err;
          $scope.sending = false;
          $scope.$apply();
        });
        request.write($scope.jsonToSend);
        request.end();

      } catch (e) {

        $scope.hasHttpError = true;
        $scope.httpErrorMessage = 'NETWORK error '+e.toString();
        $scope.sending = false;
        $scope.$apply();
      } finally {

      }
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Error: NETWORK error TypeError: First argument must be a string or
>   Buffer

Naturally it's referred to `request.write` function. My question is, how can I can send JSON to a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `request.write(JSON.stringify($scope.jsonToSend))` then when getting response parse it to json object

Comment: after i've to use JSON.parse(jsonRespond);